# Trying to append audio/video content into source buffer of media source as file slices

Tags: javascript, media-source

the code below is an experiment to see if it is possible to read pieces of audio/video data from a database and feed it into a media source buffer. I started from this [MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SourceBuffer#Examples) but changed it considerably to fit the scenario.

Ultimately, I want to read 1 MB pieces of data from a SQLite database (on the client) passed to a web extension through the native-messaging API; but, here, in this code sample, I'm selecting a video file using the file picker and slicing it into 1 MB pieces to feed into the media source following the MDN example.

The code breaks the file into 1024*1024 pieces until the final piece is smaller; and it all reaches the `append_buffer()` function and is appended to the source buffer; but the video never plays.

I'm likely doing something very stupid, but would you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

What I am trying to do here is open a file, slice off 1 MB segments, use `filereader` to read the slice as a blob arrayBuffer and append that to the video media source buffer. I wanted it to begin to play before it all loaded, but the `onplay` event doesn't fire either; and it won't play after all the blobs are appended.

I know the video that I'm trying to load in this odd manner plays because it plays in the second video element where the video.src is set to its relative path.

```
<body>
  <video controls></video>
  <label><input type="file"></input>Hard Drive</label>
  <video controls src="untitled project.mp4"></video>
</body>

"use strict";
var video_file, mediaSource, sourceBuffer,
    chunk = 1024 * 1024,
    video = document.body.firstElementChild;

video.nextElementSibling.addEventListener( 'change', open_file, false );
video.addEventListener( 'canplay', () => { console.log( "Video can play." ); video.play(); }, true );

function open_file( evt )
 {
  video_file = evt.target.files[0]; 
  fetch_video.remaining = video_file.size;
  fetch_video.start = 0;
  mediaSource = new MediaSource();
  video.src = URL.createObjectURL( mediaSource );
  mediaSource.addEventListener( 'sourceopen', openSource );  
 } // close open_file

function openSource()
 {
   console.log( "Initialized." );
   sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer( video_file.type ); 
   sourceBuffer.mode = "sequence";
   sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', append_buffers );
   append_buffers();
 }

async function append_buffers()
 {
  var buf;
  if ( fetch_video.remaining > 0 )
    {
      buf = await fetch_video();
      if ( buf !== -1 )
        sourceBuffer.appendBuffer( buf );
      else 
        console.log( "error" );
    }
  else
    mediaSource.endOfStream();
}


function fetch_video()
 {
  return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) =>
   {
    let f = fetch_video;
    f.end = f.start + Math.min( f.remaining, chunk );
    console.log( "start: " + f.start + ", end: " + f.end + ", remaining: " + f.remaining + ", end - start: " + ( f.end - f.start ) );
    if ( f.remaining > 0 )
        read_chunk( new Blob( [ video_file.slice( f.start, f.end ) ], { type : video_file.type } ) )
              .then( ( data ) => 
                    {
                      f.remaining = video_file.size - f.end;
                      f.start = f.end;
                      resolve( data );
                    },

                 ( err ) => { reject( -1 ); }
                 );
    else
      reject( - 1 );

  });
 } 

function read_chunk( blob )
  {          
    return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) =>
      {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () => { resolve( reader.result ); }; 
        reader.onerror = ( e ) => { reject(); }; 
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer( blob );
      }); // close new promise
  }
```

Comment: No error in  the console? The ContentType is generally not enpugh, you'd need the long version MIME type withe codecs details. Also try to force the mode of your SourceBuffer to "sequence".

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you. Depending on the file type I attempt to open there are different errors, even though all the types I try play when set directly as the source. For mp4, get `"Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The media resource indicated by the src attribute or assigned media provider object was not suitable."` For .mov get the error of unsupported type but the browser will play it when a video source file. Can codec details be queried from a file in JS or C? I ask because I won't know what types of audio and video files a user may load into the database and try to display.

Comment: The MediaSource API can read only a few combination of codecs, you need to check first if the incoming codec will be supported by the current browser by calling `MediaSource.isTypeSupported(mimestring)`. There is no built-in way to know what exact codec is being used in a media file, [here is an answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65163495/how-to-get-mp4s-codec-mime-information/65192029#65192029) showing a way to get it from mp4, but other containers will need other libraries. Server side you could use ffprobe.

Comment: But the best would probably be to handle the requests correctly from your server so that all you have to do is pass an url to a <video> element, and let the server handle the range requests made by the browser and deliver the corresponding chunks from the DB.

Comment: @Kaiido I'm trying to make it work offline, such that the native C app. compiled with SQLite will hold the media files the user adds and then pass it to the extension using the native-messaging API. So, no server involved.  I'm trying to avoid having to pass the entire file, concatenate the pieces, and set top object URL before it can start to play. If possible, I'd stream it. A local HTML page can load a local media file when set as element.src without a MIME type provided. Do you know why when using mediaSource to load the same file, the browser can't do whatever it does otherwise?

Comment: Because MediaSource requires the file to be set in a certain schema where each chunk is relatively independent. Media files are not like text files you can read from top to bottom. So if for instance the audio stream is all at the end of the file, MSE wouldn't be able to play the video before this part of the file is appended. (there are other reasons I'm not aware of, but that's a basic one).

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you. After setting sourceBuffer.mode to "sequence" get an error message of cannot be decoded. I'm going to try to pass the 1MB pieces, hold in an array in JS, join the array, convert to object URL, and set that as the source and see if the browser will treat it as it would a "normal" file. I suppose that without a server, local or otherwise, there is no method that will use less RAM.

Comment: Yes, concatenating all the buffers in a single Blob should do, but this means you have to fetch it all first.

Comment: @Kaiido I found a very stupid error in my code in that I forgot that the end of the `File.slice` is not included s/b f.start not f.start +1. I fixed that and now it reads all the buffers in without error, displays the duration and video controls, and then just spins. Also, there is an error at the `mediaSource.endOfStream()` line that the object is not or is no longer usable.  The individual buffers are of the expected lengths but the `mediaSource.sourceBuffers` is the same after every append. Do you have to wait until a buffer has appended before appending another? The state reads "updating".

Comment: @Kaiido I changed the code, as shown above, to not append another buffer until `updateend` and now the `onplay` event fires and the error concerning `mediaSource.endOfStream()` is no longer thrown. However, it still appears that none of the buffers make it in because, although the duration reads 34 seconds, once press play it goes to zero. And the `mediaSource.buffers` don't appear to change. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps need to read in an initial segment but don't see how to do that in this scenario nor can find any useful information on it. Not sure if it applies to server scenario only or is also at the front of every media file.